# divs in PHP, not working

Tags: php, css

I'm trying to use my css in my php script, this is what I tried:

```
    ....
    else 
    {
     echo"<html>
    <head>
    <link href='styles.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />
    </head>
    <body>
    <div id="main">
    <div id="header">
    </div>
    <div id="contentWrapper">
    <div id="leftBox">
    <div id="leftBoxContent">
    <div id="lightBox">
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div id="rightBox">
</div>
    <div id="content">
    <p>Wrong Username or Bad Password.</p>
    <p><a href='./index.php'>Click Here</a> to try again.</p>
    </div>
   <br class="clearFloat" />
   </div>
   <div id="footer"></div>
   </div>
   </body>
   </html>";
    }
   ?>
```

its my else statement of my login script, when I take away the divs the html shows fine, but leaving them in causes an error.
what am I doing wrong? do I put my css on the page??

thanks

Comment: You maybe just need an editior with syntax highlighting. They make such issues more obvious.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, I normally use editpad pro but I'm at work at the mo, what would editpad pro show me to highlight that its wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already got all the good answers. But for completeness: Another option is to keep lengthy HTML snippets in separate files. Then just do this instead of the `echo`:

```
else
{
  include("template/head+div+block.html");
}
```

If you have lots of html output like this, you will thank yourself later for making it manageable.

Comment: so would I just add the html page to that include statement then??

Comment: @addiosamigo: Just store the HTML page in the .html file. (No need for escaping anything within). The include statement then outputs it.

Comment: Requires the server to open, read and parse another file, so imo. not the best solution for short snippets.

Comment: @Aidiakapi: Indeed not for the smallest of html snippets. The parsing part is negligible, could be avoided with readfile(). But really you want to use include() here anyway, because the file ends up in the APC cache.

Comment: @Aidiakapi so it said "Another option is to keep **lengthy** HTML snippets"

Answer (score 3):

yau'll have to correct your quotation-signs as you cant use " insite of "" without escaping it. do one of these:

```
echo "this is a \"test\" ... ";
echo "this is a 'test' ... ";
echo 'this is a "test" ... ';
echo 'this is a \'test\' ... ';
```

Comment: it's worth adding the [heredoc](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc) syntax as well

Answer (score 3):

It's PHP, dude. No need to use echo at all

```
<?
else 
{
?>
<html>
  <head>
    <link href='styles.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="main">
      <div id="header"></div>
      <div id="contentWrapper">
        <div id="leftBox">
          <div id="leftBoxContent">
            <div id="lightBox"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div id="rightBox"></div>
        <div id="content">
          <p>Wrong Username or Bad Password.</p>
          <p><a href='./index.php'>Click Here</a> to try again.</p>
        </div>
        <br class="clearFloat" />
      </div>
      <div id="footer"></div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
<? } ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

It's **bad practise** to do these kinds of echos full of HTML (let's let it slip that even the below isn't MVC--that's another topic entirely). You should **come out of PHP** and then echo your HTML like so:

```
<?php function echo_menu() { ?>
  <div id="menu">
    <a href="/home">Home</a>
  </div>
<?php }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<div id="yourid" ..>
```

change to

```
<div id=\"yourid\" ..>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
else 
    {
     echo '<html>
           <head>
             <link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
           </head>
           <body>
            <div id="main">   
                 ....
          </html>';
    }
   ?>
```

But I would suggest the answer of @Col. Shrapnel.

Comment: @addiosamigo don't you see this way is ugly? no indentation, no syntax highlighting

Comment: I can't see anything, I learnt a bit about PHP in uni, and now just learning a bit to do my wedding website, so I don't know how it should look, all I care about is weather it works or not at the moment! haha

Answer (score 1):

The syntax highlighting in your question gives it away, there's a conflict with the double quotes. The solution? echo with single quotes!

```
echo '<html>
    <head>
    <link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    </head>
    <body>
    <div id="main">
    <div id="header">
    </div>
    <div id="contentWrapper">
    <div id="leftBox">
    <div id="leftBoxContent">
    <div id="lightBox">
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div id="rightBox">
</div>
    <div id="content">
    <p>Wrong Username or Bad Password.</p>
    <p><a href="./index.php">Click Here</a> to try again.</p>
    </div>
   <br class="clearFloat" />
   </div>
   <div id="footer"></div>
   </div>
   </body>
   </html>';
```

You could also use the [heredoc](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc) syntax:

```
echo <<<HTMLBLOCK
<a href="#">Double quotes</a>
<a href='#'>..and single quotes!</a>
HTMLBLOCK;
```

Comment: No, this would lead to the same error, because single quotes are used on the first href-attribute in the first link!

Comment: Using heredoc would solve the problem so you should probably edit your answer and use heredoc syntax.

Comment: He changed it to double quotes.

Answer (score 1):

Use quotation marks consistently. Now you use single quotes with `link` but double quotes with all the other tags. Change your `link` tag to

```
<link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

Then you can use single quotes around the whole string like:

```
....
else 
{
 echo '<html>
<head>
...
</body>
</html>';
}
```

Comment: @addiosamigo The answer you accepted suggested just the same thing.

Comment: I've just realised the echo statement was in double quotes and the div statements are in single quotes, that worked but not what you suggested. thanks

Comment: @addiosamigo Seems you don't get it. You should use double quotes in your HTML then it can be safey enclosed between single quotes. Like I showed in my example.

Comment: so single quotes around the echo statement and double quotes around everything else?

Comment: @addiosamigo Basicly yes. - Strictly speaking single quotes **around the quoted HTML string** and double quoutes **inside the HTML string**. You don't even have to quote attributes inside HTML, but it's safer to quote them. The most important thing is to be consequential about them, do not mix them.

Answer (score 1):

Old fun method

```
echo <<< OUT
<html>
<head>
<link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
...
OUT;
```

everyone forgot it, right? :)

Answer (score 1):

Besides using another type of quotation marks, escaping and so on, I would highly recommend to [separate your concerns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns): Why not using a html-file (or a template)?

Answer (score 0):

escape double quotes in div attributes

```
<div id=\"main\">
```

like this

Answer (score 0):

You are having quotes in there that end your echoed string.

Either escape them with a backslash, or use one single quotes to quote the string and double quotes in it, or vice versa.

However, if you do not use any PHP variables or code in the block, you could also enter non-PHP mode by using `?>` before the HTML and reenter PHP mode afterwards with `<?php`.
This has the benefit that many editors can syntax-highlight both PHP and HTML properly.